# Is it possible to get OS env variables into postman?

Tags: variables, environment-variables, postman

Is it possible set some environment variable from the os inside postman?

I want to use some environment variables from my linux inside postman without duplicate it. Is it possible? Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is still an open feature request on Postman GitHub: [Feature Request: read variables from OS environment](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1603).

The way around is to create a method that fetches required OS environment variables, call that method in the Pre-request script and store its value to the Postman environment variables whenever you need them.

Comment: Thanks @Div. I will try to do a method to this.

Comment: still is this open ?

Comment: @YasarArafath, yeah it seems